# Basic ANTLR4 use in Visual Studio 2017 (C++)

Tags: c++, antlr4

I'm trying to use ANTLR4 in Visual Studio 2018 (C++, Windows 10), and I simply do not understand what to do, despite reading the [getting started](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/getting-started.md) and the [C++ target readme](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/cpp-target.md), and looking at a dozen other places.

I can take the grammar suggested from the getting started page, and use the ANTLR4 jar to create the HelloParser.h, HelloParser.cpp, etc files. I have downloaded the runtime (antlr4-cpp-runtime-4.7.1-vs2015) as well. But what am I supposed to do with these files in order to include them in my main solution/project? Let's say my solution is in C:\Users\UserName\source\repos\test.

Comment: Have you looked at the [C++ demo](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/tree/master/runtime/Cpp/demo)? It will answer exactly these questions.

Comment: I did. I can do all of it up to "and run." But it generates a .dll or .lib, and I'm not sure what to do with them. Are THOSE the files I use in my own project? Because the demo has a main() that seems like it should run, but it doesn't, of course, because it's a .dll or .lib. Or do I set things up the same way as the example (somehow) and then it will let me use the parser?

Comment: It's not a lib. The demo is a terminal application. You probably only built the runtime, not the entire demo.